# Regex - is there any way to conditionally convert to a literal?

Tags: regex

Simply put, I want to test for the presence of a pattern in a string and effectively return "Yes" if it's found, and "No" if not. Said another way, I need to (effectively) convert the entire string into either "Yes" or "No" depending upon if the pattern is present or not.

So, for example, if my pattern is (arbitrarily) "found", then:

Example 1: *This string does not contain the pattern*

Would be converted to: *No*

Example 2: *I have **found** the string!*

Would be converted to: *Yes*

I've been banging my head against the wall for an hour now but just don't see how to do this. Apologies if this is really obvious and somehow I completely missed it.

Background:
I'm using a tool called ADBulkExport that allows you to quickly configure and download selected Active Directory data and export it into a database.

My client uses a specific notation in the AD displayName field to indicate if the person is a contractor, which is a parenthesised comment after the person's name. E.g. "Charlie Lotridge (C)" means I'm a contractor.

ADBulkExport allows you to introduce a regex conversion on the value pulled down from AD. So, using this feature, I want to add a new column called (something like) "IsContractor", which would have a simple "Yes"/"No" string value. But to fill it I need to, effectively, convert that displayName field value into Yes or No depending on if that parenthesized expression is present.

Comment: What programming language are you trying to achieve this in? Depending on the language, you may not even need regex!

Comment: This is not possible using a pure regex replace operation. Why wouldn't you just use a regex to perform the match and set Yes or No outside of regex?

Comment: @kubunto: I've added a background description to my question which should explain why regex is the only option.

Comment: Can you process the file *twice* using the tool? Ie export once to a temp DB then export from that to the target DB?

Comment: @Bohemian: Unfortunately no, only a single pass.

Comment: @CharlieLotridge then there's no way to do it. The best you can hope for is capturing 2 parts of the input each of which could be used as the two output values, but it would be ugly. Why can't you just run an SQL query over the result to do the conversion after you've loaded the data into a table?

Comment: @Bohemian: yes, I'll use SQL to affect the solution, thanks.